# Notifications when the app is turned off

Tags: java, android, notifications

I wonder if it is possible to have notifications show up even if the app is turned off.

say for example I have an app and I set some kind of notification for 13.00 the next day and then turn the app off or restart my phone or something.

Is it possible to still get a notification in the notification bar with some text that starts the app or do the app need to run in the background to be able to use notifications?

if it is possible, what is the best way to do this? (get a notification at a certain time that starts the app) and if not, how do you recommend doing notifications?

The type of notifcations I want to do are reminder notifications.

thanks for all help!

Comment: have you tried looking at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or using [GCM Messages](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) yet?

Comment: I've looked at GCM messages, but Im making a simple app and don't want to ask for Internet permission

Comment: How do you `turn the app off`?

Answer (score 1):

A combination of AlarmManager and Service will help you to perform the task you are looking for, I had performed this thing.Check out the android tutorials for it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a background service. See this [Android Services tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).

In the background service, your app should check periodically and when necessary, create and issue new notifications. See this [Android Notifications tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html).

The background service can be set to automatically start when the phone is restarted, and to re-issue any uncleared notification again.

Many apps such as *Gmail* already do this. Although you must be careful in resource usage or Android might kill your service.